# How to make markers have their origin at the bottom left?

Tags: css, leaflet

I'm using LeafletJS, but I can't work out how to change the position of the markers' origins.

Currently, the origin of markers (the imaginary point where they are "glued" to the map) is at the top left.

I need it to be the bottom left, as my marker HTML looks a little like a flag.

```
|--------+
|this is |
|a marker|
|--------+
|
```

Is there a way of doing this with LeafletJS?

Or do I need to do some horribly complex CSS?  (The markers expand vertically and horizontally, according to their content.)

---

Update: I'm creating the markers with:

```
var html = '<div class="tag_main_pedestrian">' + content + '</div><div class="triangle_pedestrian"></div>';
var icon = L.divIcon({html: html, className: 'tag_icon_pedestrian'});
        this.markers[beacon] = L.marker(this.pedestrians[index].geotag,
        {icon: icon});
this.markers[beacon].addTo(this.map);
```

Comment: Check the `iconAnchor` property of a custom icon, which allows you to specify which point on the icon to align with the marker coordinates. https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#icon

Comment: How are you creating your markers right now? Are you using `L.Icon` or `L.DivIcon`? Can you please include a tiny bit of code about that?

Comment: @peeebeee I have tried iconAnchor, but it needs pixel values.  I do not know how big each marker will be (unless I create a duplicate div offscreen and measure it).

Comment: @IvanSanchez I've updated the question to add creation code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed you would need to use your own CSS to move your icon upwards, but it should not be "*horribly complex*".

Typically using CSS transform should do the trick:

```js
var paris = [48.86, 2.35];
var map = L.map('map').setView(paris, 11);

var myHtml = '<div class="iconContent" id="content"></div>';

var myIcon = L.divIcon({
  html: myHtml,
  className: 'tag_icon_pedestrian',
  iconSize: null,
});

L.marker(paris, {
  icon: myIcon,
}).addTo(map);

var inputEl = document.getElementById('input');
var contentEl = document.getElementById('content');
inputEl.addEventListener('input', updateContent);
updateContent();

function updateContent() {
  contentEl.innerHTML = inputEl.value;
}

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
.tag_icon_pedestrian {
  height: 0; /* Avoid a "ghost" clickable area */
}

.iconContent {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transform: translateY(-100%); /* Move your icon its full content height */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-IkGU/uDhB9u9F8k+2OsA6XXoowIhOuQL1NTgNZHY1nkURnqEGlDZq3GsfmdJdKFe1k1zOc6YU2K7qY+hF9AodA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<input value="Lorem ipsum" id="input" />
<div id="map" style="height: 160px"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very interesting.  I've gone with a zero-sized icon and an extra div, as it's probably more compatible with older browsers.

Comment: You saved my day :)  I'm having a div icon changing html-content which is not under my control. Now the content grows up and i dont have to calc the anchor anymore on the fly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS code:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

Someone have already asked something related to this here:

[CSS - Placement of a div in the lower left-hand corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50430/css-placement-of-a-div-in-the-lower-left-hand-corner)

Hope it help you.

Comment: Thanks, that was part of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

My approach to this problem is to make the `L.DivIcon` contain a zero-size, relatively-positioned `<div>`, and inside that, another `<div>`. The inside `<div>` is positioned absolutely (in relation to the nearest ancestor with an explicit `position` CSS style, which is the outer one).

The code looks like the following. Note I'm adding some borders just to see where each `<div>` is:

```
var html = `
<div style="position: relative; width: 0; height: 0; border: 3px black solid">
  <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; border:2px red solid; background:white">
    Null Island
  </div>
</div>
`;

var icon = L.divIcon({html: html});

L.marker([0, 0], {icon: icon}).addTo(map);
```

And it looks like this (or [try it yourself](https://plnkr.co/edit/vo5uYWDApipyKZ75sezV?p=preview)):

[image: screenshot]

The other answers are valid, but IMHO dealing with `position: absolute` is somewhat cleaner than `position: fixed` and `!important` CSS rules.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to shrink the leaflet-marker-icon to a point using:

```
div.tag_icon_pedestrian {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    width: 0px !important;
    height: 0px !important;
}
```

and interpose another div:

```
var html = '<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0;"><div class="tag_main_pedestrian">' + content + '</div><div class="triangle_pedestrian"></div></div>';
```