# Simple: Floating image at the bottom left of website

Tags: wordpress

I just want to make an image float at the bottom left of the screen, across the entire website.

The image is about 200x200px and links out to another part of the website.

Comment: Do you want the image to stay at a fixed position as you scroll down?

Comment: Check out [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50430/css-placement-of-a-div-in-the-lower-left-hand-corner). You'll have to put the CSS and HTML somewhere; hopefully you're familiar with how to edit your theme. Alternatively, it's likely there's a WP plugin that does this already, search for stuff like "floating action button" or "sticky notification".

Comment: That's perfect MarsAndBack :D

Comment: What have you tried? Include your current code. What problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite simple solution for this. As you want to float the image and link it to to some other part, you need to put img in anchor tag.

For e.g.

```
<a href="link-of-the-site"><img src="image-source-link" height="200" width="200"></a>
```

css

```
a{
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
left:0;
z-index:111111;
}
```

"position:fixed" will fix the a element but you need to tell where it should be fixed.
For that we have bottom:0;left:0; i.e., fix on the bottom left of the page.
z-index is very important for this element as it will be overlapping with a number of other elements on the page. The one with the higher z-index will have better visibility.

I hope this solves your problem.